# Get the windows running process description In java

Tags: java, cmd

```
       import java.io.BufferedReader;
       import java.io.IOException;
       import java.io.InputStreamReader;
       public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                String line;

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
                (System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line); // <-- Parse data here.
           }
           input.close();
           } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
           }
    }

}
```

The output of this program shows the process list from windows task manager .....but i also need the Description of the running process  ??? How do i get that???

Answer (score 0):

`tasklist.exe` takes an optional parameter `/v` for verbose. This outputs the description

Example

```
taskmgr.exe 5648 Console 1 18,280 K Running 0:00:00 Windows Task Manager
```

You'll need to update your call to exec() to pass the "/v". Full example including parsing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String taskListExe = System.getenv("windir") + "\\system32\\" + "tasklist.exe";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { taskListExe, "/v" });

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\s+(\\d+).*(\\d+:\\d+:\\d+)\\s+(.*?)");
    String line;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s, pid = %s, description = %s", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2),
                    matcher.group(4)));
        }
    }
    input.close();
}
```

Output

```
firefox.exe, pid = 3152, description = cmd - Get the windows running process description In java - Stack Overfl
taskmgr.exe, pid = 5648, description = Windows Task Manager
System Idle Process, pid = 0, description = N/A
```

Comment: your program output the window title but i need the description ....please see the task manager there is a column named description...where the exact file name are shown...

Comment: @ShakibAhmed Apologies I misunderstood the difference between title and description.